# Python tuples sorting based on last element

Tags: python, list, dictionary, terminal, tuples

Here is my question i have `tuple1=[(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)]` i want to sort tuple based on last digit of each tuple so the resultant will look like this 
`output=[(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]`
below is my code

```
    i=0
for x in tuples:
    c.append(x[len(x)-1])
    last=sorted(c)
    for y in last.iteritems():
        if(y in x[len(x)-1]):
            print x             
            #b.insert(i,x)
i=i+1
```

after running iam getting an error message

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "x.py", line 47, in <module>
   sort_last([(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)])
  File "x.py", line 35, in sort_last
 if(y in x[len(x)-1]):
  TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: My bad, that question is not about sorting, but the solution is identical: specify the `key` function to `sort` or `sorted`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Specify the `key` argument in the `sorted` function.

```
>>> tuple1=[(1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)]
>>> output = sorted(tuple1, key=lambda x: x[-1])
>>> print output
[(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)]
```

The `sorted` function (as well as the `list.sort` method) has an optional `key` argument which specifies what to sort the list on.

Comment: +1 for this elegant solution.

Comment: yup it works.. but is there any other method without using 'lambda' i mean using for loop itself....

Comment: If you need it in reverse order you can also add the `reverse` keyword: `output = sorted(tuple1, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)`

Comment: @Friend this is the most pythonic way to do that, otherwise you should rely on any sorting algorithm and implement it yourself, dealing with bugs, efficiency, etc... are you sure you want to do that? (Rule of thumb: do not reinvent the wheel)